# Global variables in class function

Tags: php, class, global

I made a irc twitch bot and i have implemented multi threading but it have caused loots of errors.

My problem is that i have functions, example:

```
function isMod($username){
global $mods;

if(in_array($username,$mods) !== FALSE){
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

But there is a problem if i call the function from a class the "global" tag seams to not work so $mods will remain null. How can i fix it?

I have tried to use

```
$globals['mods']
```

But it is not seaming to work either.

I could do it like

```
function isMod($username, $mods){

if(in_array($username,$mods) !== FALSE){
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

But i want to avoid that.

Comment: Your best bet is to avoid using global variables altogether. You could do this by passing `$mods` as an argument to the `isMod` function.

Comment: @WillVousden I want to avoid that because im using the function in many places. And it takes longer to write an extra argument :P

Comment: You should really consider passing $mods as an argument to the function. It's better than always setting variables globals.

Comment: What's the point of that function anyway? Why not simply use `in_array` when you need to? Seems like an unnecessary abstraction, after all you can reduce it to a one liner `return in_array($username,$mods)`.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes i know but the place i need to use it is in another function and the function is 

function permit_command($username, $command, $message){

and it's a function i can't add arguments to.

Comment: Nobody whants loots of errors :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with globals, try to use `$GLOBALS['mods']` instead.

```
function isMod($username){
    if(in_array($username,$GLOBALS['mods']) !== FALSE){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

$GLOBALS['mods'] = array('joe');

class Test {
    function foo(){
        var_dump(isMod('joe'));
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->foo();
```

[`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) is available everywhere, just like e.g. `$_GET`.

Comment: @albin900 I added an tested example.

Comment: Thats not my case.. First a file with the isMod function is included then the class is called in the class there is a public function and in that there is a line: isMod( $someusername ).

Comment: @albin900 changed the example regarding to your comment. works for me. just take care to use the `$GLOBALS` thing instead of the `global` keyword in all places.